# Can a mapping be from 1 to many?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm starting to learn linear algebra from Lang's Linear Algebra, and am a little confused about the definition of mapping. A mapping is defined to be an association which to every element of $S$ associates an element of $S'$, and a function is a special mapping from a set into the set of numbers ($\mathbb{R,C,K}$). I know that for functions, each element in $S$ only maps to one element in $S'$. Is this true for all maps, just linear maps, or completely untrue?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is true for all maps.

Comment: A mapping is a linear function from $S$ to another vector space $S'$ - it can't be one to many. A function(al) here is a linear map from the vector space to the vector space of the underlying field

Comment: "a function is a special mapping...into one of $\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{K}\}$" – that definition is not universally accepted. Normally, "function" is basically a synonym for "mapping"; the special case where a vector space $V$ over field $\mathbb{K}$ maps to $\mathbb{K}$ is called a [_functional_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: *Mapping* is used synonymously with *function*.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I was under the impression that linear map are only 1 type of maps and that non linear maps exists. Otherwise I don't understand why it would necessary to check for linearity.

Comment: That is correct. There are the usual kind of not-necessarily-linear maps/functions (which aren't especially useful in linear algebra) and linear maps (which preserve the structure of a vector space). The linear map from the vector space $V$ to the vector space of its scalars is given the special name of a functional.